# Why does $1+p+p^2+\dotsb+p^{n-1}=\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

> $$y_n=\rho^ny_0+(1+\rho+\rho^2+\cdots+\rho^{n-1})b.$$
>   If $\rho \not=1$, we can write this solution in the more compact form $$y_n=\rho^ny_0+\frac{1-\rho^n}{1-\rho}b.$$

This is from Elem. Diff. Eq. - Boyce, DiPrima.

How was the more compact form  derived?  In my calculus text: $1+p+p^2+\dotsb+p^{n-1}=\frac1{1-p}$.
So where did Boyce/DiPrima get that numerator from?

Comment: Do the know polynomial long division?

Comment: Just substitute numbers in your formula to assure that it is wrong.

Comment: First of all, I suspect you are misreading your calculus book The value $\frac{1}{1-p}$ only equals the limit as $n\to\infty$. It can't equal the finite sum, since the finite sum obviously differs as $n$ differs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line you write is incorrect, $1+p+\ldots+p^{n-1}$ ***approaches*** to $\frac1{1-p}$ assuming that $|p|<1$.

Namely, if $|p|<1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\ldots+p^n)=\dfrac1{1-p}$.

This is true exactly because $1+\ldots+p^{n-1}=\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}$, and when $|p|<1$, taking $n$ to infinity yields $p^n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be
$$
(1-p)(1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1})=(1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1})-(p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1}+p^n)=1-p^n
$$
giving
$$
1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1}=\frac{1-p^{n}}{1-p}, \quad p\neq1,
$$
moreover if $|p|<1$, then $p^n \rightarrow 0$ and you get
$$
1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1}+\ldots=\frac{1}{1-p},\quad |p|<1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $|p|<1$, the infinite sum $1+p+p^2+\dots=\frac{1}{1-p}$.  The finite sum $1+p+\dots+p^{n-1}=\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}$. This can be easily seen by multiplying both sides by $1-p$.